# Hash Map in Java 8 sorts by default?

Tags: java, collections

Java 8 Hash map is by default sorting without implementing Comparable and Comparator.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("ac", "ac");
    map.put("ab", "ab");
    map.put("ae", "ae");
    map.put("ad", "ad");
    map.put("az", "aa");


    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+":::::"+entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Java 8 OutPut(Default provide sorting by key)

```
ab:::::ab
ac:::::ac
ad:::::ad
ae:::::ae
az:::::aa
```

Java 7 Output

```
az:::::aa
ac:::::ac
ad:::::ad
ab:::::ab
ae:::::ae
```

My question is this: is this a feature or a bug in Java 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is completely incidental. `HashMap` does not provide any guarantees of order among its entries.

In fact, just adding `map.put("zz", "zz");` causes the result to no longer be sorted:

```
zz:::::zz
ab:::::ab
ac:::::ac
ad:::::ad
ae:::::ae
az:::::aa
```

Comment: but why java 7 result is different then java 8?

Comment: Because the implementation of it changed (in a compatible way) in Java 8.

Comment: I had a similar behavior with collections on different platforms (OSX and Windows). I learned to look at the API specs and not the results!